# How would I extract a substring from a string that contains parentheses using python?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have the following string:

> The quick brown fox, the cat in the (hat) and the dog in the pound. The Cat in THE (hat):

I need help with extracting the following text:

> 1) the cat in the (hat)
>
> 2) The Cat in THE (hat)

I have tried the following:

```
p1 = """The quick brown fox, the cat in the (hat) and the dog in the pound. The Cat in THE (hat)"""
pattern = r'\b{var}\b'.format(var = p1)
with io.open(os.path.join(directory,file), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as textfile:
    for line in textfile:
        result = re.findall(pattern, line)
print (result)
```

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: What is the rule by which you selected what you wanted extracted? At the moment, `result = ["the cat in the (hat)", "The Cat in THE (hat)"]` makes as much sense as anything. Do you want the parenthesised words and the four preceding words? The second enclosing noun phrase? The maximal two substrings that are equal when compared case-insensitively while containing `(hat)`?

Comment: the word (hat) would always be in parentheses. the "barebones" phrase I wanted extracted is "the cat in the (hat). in my strings, I may have variations where "the" may be all uppercase or "cat" may have an uppercase C.

Comment: I think you just need to escape the input for regex usage and add the `/i` modifier

Comment: What is the value of `{var}`?

Comment: Do you mean like `[,.]\s(.+?\([^()]+\))`  https://regex101.com/r/tRfWEq/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks for the feedback, however I want to match the exact string, instead of using punctuation as markers.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus var = p1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly matching that string, you can use this regex. To generalize for the future, the `(?i)` in the beginning makes it ignore the case and use `\` to escape the parentheses.

```
import re
regex = re.compile('(?i)the cat in the \(hat\)')
string = 'The quick brown fox, the cat in the (hat) and the dog in the pound. The Cat in THE (hat):'
regex.findall(string)
```

Result:

```py
['the cat in the (hat)', 'The Cat in THE (hat)']
```